# Transforming a path in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, path

I want to transform a given path in python 3 and all this under windows.

As a preliminary information: in my application I use the tool Flexible I/O tester(https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html).

To start *Flexible I/O tester* it needs the drive path in a special formatting. This formatting looks for example like this: "G\:test".

A file is then created in the G: drive. Now I try to delete this file in the run of my application.
Unfortunately I can't just do `os.remove(file_path)` because the path doesn't correspond to a standard path.

So I have to transform the path *"G\:test"* to *"G:\test"*.

Does anyone happen to know how I can best solve this whole problem?

thanks a lot

I have already tried the following:

```
path = r"G\\:test"
formatted_path = ""

for i in range(len(path)):
    if i < len(path) - 1 and path[i] == "\\" and path[i + 1] == ":":
        formatted_path += ":"
    else:
        formatted_path += path[i]

print(formatted_path)  # G:\test
```

Unfortunately I can't use a raw string, because then the call with Flexible I/O tester won't start.

**Edit:**
Thanks for the suggestions.

sorry for the contradictions..Again maybe for better explanation:

My complete setup of the call function looks like this:

def run_fio(self, drive_letter, runtime=None, output=None, fio_args=None):

```
# Set default arguments if none are provided
fio_args = fio_args or self.DEFAULT_FIO_ARGS_WRITE

if not output:
    output = self.log_path

if runtime:
    fio_args = list(fio_args)
    fio_args.append("--runtime=%d" %runtime)

fio_args.append("--filename=%s" %drive_letter)

# Construct the FIO command
fio_cmd_args = [self.fio_path]
fio_cmd_args.extend(fio_args)
fio_cmd = " ".join(fio_cmd_args)

# Start the FIO process and capture the output
p = subprocess.Popen(fio_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Here fio_cmd is the assembled Flexible I/O tester call. This looks with me in the source code as follows:

```
'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\dev\\tools\\fio\\fio.exe --group_reporting --bs=256k --size=20G --numjobs=32 --iodepth=4 --loops=1 --thread --ioengine=windowsaio --direct=1 --fsync_on_close=1 --time_based --name=WriteTest --rw=write --runtime=10 --filename=G\\:test'
```

The call in my main application then looks like this:

```
test = fioTest.run_fio('G\\:test',10)
```

I want to transofrmate the mandatory path "G\:test" into a normal path "G:\test" in the run_fio function so that I can delete the created "test"-file.

According to the description I need the extra "" and then the ":". Here is a screenshot of it: fio parameter description

The problem is when I do something like this:

```
raw_path = r"G\\:test"
    
'C:\\Users\test\Desktop\dev\tools\fio\fio.exe --group_reporting --bs=256k --size=20G --numjobs=32 --iodepth=4 --loops=1 --thread --ioengine=windowsaio --direct=1 --fsync_on_close=1 --time_based --name=WriteTest --rw=write --runtime=10 --filename={raw_path}'
```

Unfortunately, the tool call does not work anymore and it cannot be started.

For completeness here the whole documentation of the tool: https://git.kernel.dk/?p=fio.git;a=blob;f=HOWTO;h=025443be406669ece150b28858c67ed9cb2f56d9;hb=HEAD

Comment: Is this a single backslash or a double backslash in the special path? Description and code contradict.

Comment: `r"G\\:test"` is NOT `"G\:test"`, so maybe that's why it does not start. Try `r"G\:test"`. Also are you sure it's `"G\:test"` that you need and not `"G:\test"`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you misread the documentation. It tells you to **escape colons in the path name**. I can't find anything in that documentation that tells you to remove backslashes from the path, like you seem to be trying to do. Emphasis mine:

> Each colon in the wanted path must be escaped with a `\` character. For instance, if the path is `/dev/dsk/foo@3,0:c` then you would use `filename=/dev/dsk/foo@3,0\:c` and **if the path is `F:\filename` then you would use `filename=F\:\filename`.**

Escaping the colon in `F:` turns `F:` into `F\:`. But that shouldn't change the `\filename` part. `F\:` + `\filename` = `F\:\filename`. If you tell it `filename=F\:filename`, you've removed a backslash from the path, and you're telling it to look at the path `F:filename`, not `F:\filename`.

---

`str.replace()` in Python is an easy way to convert between unescaped `:` and escaped `\:`:

```
>>> 'G:\\test'.replace(':', '\\:')
'G\\:\\test'
>>> 'G\\:\\test'.replace('\\:', ':')
'G:\\test'
```